# Can underscore be forced as a word splitter without a full-text parser plugin?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, plugins

Is there any way in MySQL to force underscore to become a word splitter character (like space or dash) without having to use a fulltext parser plugin?

If not, does such a plugin already exist or do I have to learn to make my own?

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of such a plugin. Sure, you could make your own plugin.

However, I have a rather wild suggestion if you can afford the diskspace.

Let's take an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    txt text,
    primary key (id),
    fulltext txt (txt)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Let's say a table like this is populated already.

Suppose you want to index any words such as

- abc_def_ghi
- innodb_file_per_table
- key_buffer_size

You may want to create a separate column with the underscores replaced with blanks. You will have to perform the following conversion

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable_new LIKE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new ADD txtsrch TEXT;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new ADD FULLTEXT txt_txtsrtch (txt,txtsrch);
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new DROP INDEX txt;
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable_new (id,txt,txtsrch)
SELECT id,txt,REPLACE(txt,'_',' ') FROM mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

Once done, the table should look like this

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    txt text,
    txsrch text,
    primary key (id),
    fulltext txtsrch (txt,txtsrch)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This will index the data both ways. Consequently, this blows up the table and index files in size.

You will have to do searching with the following clause

```
MATCH(txt,txtsrch) AGAINST ...
```

Please perform this on a test server, look at the increased size of the new table and index.  You can decide whether this table layout provides the data you want with tokens separated.

Give it a Try !!!