# Multi-Column Full Text Search Going Very Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, full-text-search

I have a full text index on a table `articles` for the columns `content`, `title` and `keywords`

When doing the search on each of the columns, like so `select count(1) from articles where match(content,title,keywords) against ('cats' in boolean mode)`, the results take between 12 and 15 seconds.

But doing the columns individually (`select count(1) from articles where match(content) against ('cats' in boolean mode)`) typically takes less than 50ms.

Why does searching the 3 columns take more than 100 times longer than all of them separately?

This isn't a question of how to make it faster, but instead is more asking "why is it so slow?"

**Table/Indexes**

```
id           int(30)       PK       auto_increment
url          varchar(1024)
title        varchar(255)  FULLTEXT
content      text          FULLTEXT
keywords     varchar(1024) FULLTEXT
comments     text
created_date int(11)
posted_date  int(11)
```

**Explains**

This first one is the multi-column query:

[image]

This second is the new much faster query that runs the 3 columns separately then unions them (query cache was cleared).

[image]

**Full Text Column Order**

[image]

**Use/Force Index with Explain**

[image]

Comment: What's your table and index definitions? You can use `EXPLAIN` to get details about query plan and execution steps and timings.

Comment: Can you also please add `EXPLAIN`s for both queries (ideally 4). How long does it take to search `content` column?

Comment: @Stoleg, I updated the question.

Comment: The reason is simple - FT index is not used. In first query put columns in the same order as index: title, content, keywords.

Comment: Screenshotted "Show Indexes from articles". My query is in the proper order.

Comment: Table definition has columns in different order. Try using query hints `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX`. Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: updated with a screenshot showing both use and force and their respective explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## PROBLEM

From the posts in your question, I see 3 FULLTEXT indexes. There is one for each column.

Why did the query work at all ? MySQL worked with whatever it had. In your case, it searched by a full table scan. That's what the MySQL Query optimizer decided on.

## SOLUTION

What you really need is a single FULLTEXT index with all 3 columns

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT content_title_keywords_ndx (content,title,keywords);
```

Only then can you say

```
match(content,title,keywords) against ('cats' in boolean mode)
```

I have suggested making compound FULLTEXT indexes before

- `Mar 16, 2012` : [Speed up search across multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/speed-up-search-across-multiple-columns/15178#15178)
- `Oct 13, 2012` : [Can underscore be forced as a word splitter without a full-text parser plugin?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25883/can-underscore-be-forced-as-a-word-splitter-without-a-full-text-parser-plugin/26904#26904)
- [**All my posts about FULLTEXT indexing and searching**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A877%20%5Bmysql%5D%20match%20against)

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: That worked like a charm. Can't believe it took 2 days for that ;).

Comment: I am sorry I took so long to get to it.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA is the order of columns, in the index, is important at all? I.e. will there be difference between match(content,title,keywords) and match(keywords, content,title) when having the same index content_title_keywords_ndx (content,title,keywords) ? Thanks